# Selenium Automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Is there any way in Selenium ide, so that we get list and handlers for all controls provided on any page? 
So if we get that we can test that one by one using RC and it'll greatly helpful when there are more then 40 controls on page. In that case, it'll become very tiresome to record for all.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Is there any chance you could rephrase it? What do you want to test with Selenium?

Comment: Actually, I want to test different controls on a page and those are enormous in number so we can't just record each control. So thinking that if there's a way to grab all controls info like(tabs, checkboxes etc.) then I could export those to python and can execute my scripts with Selenium RC with modifications or combinations.

Answer (score 2):

In Selenium you can use `getXpathCount` to get the number of matching elements and then loop through them. The following Java example will output the IDs of the checkboxes on the page:

```
int checkboxCount = selenium.getXpathCount("//input[@type='checkbox']").intValue();
for (int i = 1; i < checkboxCount + 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(selenium.getAttribute("//body/descendant::input[@type='checkbox'][" + i + "]@id"));
}
```

In the WebDriver API (to be merged into Selenium 2) there is a `findElements` method that returns a list of matching elements. The above example would look something like:

```
for (WebElement checkbox : driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@checkbox]"))) {
    System.out.println(checkbox.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Comment: How could find, what all type of controls are there on page ?

Comment: You could just check to see if a type of 'control' is present using by trying to find it. The example I gave would find checkboxes, but you could find other elements by modifying the XPath. If there were no checkboxes on the page, the given example would just output nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible to do with getEval and a Javascript routine to examine the DOM. There's an example here for looking for the id's of checkboxes on a page: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#executing-javascript-from-your-test